# Gitane Frame Identification Year

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Was wondering if anyone can verify year of the Gitane frame

Thanks
Damian

[image]

Comment: what is on with its handlebar?!

Comment: @BenPoulter common bodge for people who found drops too hunched over.  Consider it the same as a negative-offset stem, so handling becomes more "tiller-like" where you push left to go right.  Remember a lof of these bikes are 80s, which predated the straight flat bar, and your only other option would have been riser bars.

Comment: Why do you care what year it was made? Beyond satisfying curiosity, what difference would it make to anything?

Comment: Turning the brake levers that way is quite dangerous, unless you want a second belly button!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to point out the features that make it a 70s bike.

- Cottered cranks.  They went away in the late 70s.
- 3-leg spider in the middle of the cranks - that's old looking, but the thin cranks imply a racer.  Do get it off the ground, you're damaging the big chainring like that.

And these are the aberrations:

- The cable stops on the top tube - most bikes used a full brake cable housing with clips, not an exposed inner cable.
- No lugs - at least none visible in the photo.  This looks like a smoothly welded steel frame.
- Down tube derailleur seems to have a thing under it - is not overly clear in the photo.

The saddle is too new, and there appear to be no wheels, but its very close to being complete and rideable.  You need a new chain and new brake pads too.